# Extract text after blank line and specific word in R

Tags: r

I have a dataset with multiple news articles. Each news article has classification at the bottom of the text. I want to extract the subject-tags:

> Classification
>
> Language: ENGLISH
>
> Publication-Type: Newswire
>
> Subject: MANAGERS & SUPERVISORS (90%); POLLS & SURVEYS (90%); HUMAN
> MACHINE INTERACTION (78%)
>
> Company:  ABC-Company

The number of tags can substantially differ across the dataset. Also not all news articles have the information on publication type or language.

So far I've tried:

```
y <- str_extract(x$Text, "Subject: .*")
```

This worked well, until I found some news reports contain the "subject" part in their body. R then extracts whatever text comes after that.
I am now looking for a way to adjust my code to account for the blank line that always precedes "Subject: ".

Simply adding a blank like did not work (it works in Python, that is why I tried).

Best case, I would adjust the above code to extract the information after the word subject only if that word in preceded by a blank line and only if those are after the word classification. This would make my code more robust.

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example of your data.

Comment: How do I do that? The dataset has a single column only and multiple lines, each with some text XXXXX and then below that text is the Classification part shown above. If I share a set of strings like x <- c("XXX Classification Language: ..." I will run into exactly the issue I have now - how to account for blank lines when writing strings (i.e., how do I get that formatting done)

Answer (score 0):

I believe I found a way. I added `\n` to my string.

```
y <- str_extract(x$Text, "\nSubject: .*")
```

Worked for me.